# Proving that $\{f \in End(A): \forall a \in A:|a|<\infty \implies f(a)=0\}$ is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, solution-verification

Let $A$ be an abelian group. I need to prove that

$I = \{f \in End(A): f(a)= 0 \ \text{for all $a$ of finite order}\}$,

is an ideal of $\text{End}(A)$. It isn't hard to prove that $I$ is a subgroup of $End(A)$, but it is quite hard to prove that:

$g(x) \cdot f(x)$ and $f(x) \cdot g(x)$ are in $I$ with $f(x)\in I$ and $g(x) \in End(A)$.

I thought that if you multiply $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ and you take an element $a$ that $g(a)*f(a) = g(a)*0 = 0$, so $g(x)f(x)=0$ for $x$ with finite order so $g(x)f(x) \in I$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Why did you think it was hard?

Comment: Is $A$ an abelian group?

Comment: @ Lord Farin, i thought it was hard because in my proof, i didn't use the fact that A is an abelian group.

Comment: @egreg

Yes, thanks for the response btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an abelian group, the multiplication on $\operatorname{End}(A)$ is the composition. It's customary to write $A$ additively and I'll use this convention.

It's clear that $0\in I$. If $f,g\in I$, then $(f+g)(a)=f(a)+g(a)=0+0=0$ for all $a$ of finite order.

Now, let $f\in I$ and $g$ be an arbitrary endomorphism. Saying $a$ has finite order means that $na=0$ for some integer $n>0$.

Since $ng(a)=g(na)$, we see that if $a$ has finite order, then also $g(a)$ has finite order. Therefore
$$
(fg)(a)=f(g(a))=0
$$
by hypothesis. Proving that $gf\in I$ is even easier: if $a$ has finite order, then
$$
(gf)(a)=g(f(a))=g(0)=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove this in the following way: let $T = \{ a \in A \hspace{1mm} | \hspace{1mm} a \text{ of finite order}\}$ be the so-called torsion subgroup of $A$. Observe that the set $I$ that you describe is precisely the kernel of the following ring homomorphism

$\phi: \text{End}(A) \rightarrow \text{End}(T), \hspace{1mm} f \mapsto f|_{T}$,

where $f|_{T}$ denotes the restriction of $f$ tot $T$. Now use the fact that the kernel of every ring homomorphism is an ideal (every ideal even arises in this way), to conclude the proof.

An interesting [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467362/endomorphism-rings-and-torsion-subgroups), to which I don't know the answer myself, is whether the map $\phi$ is surjective or not.