# Are these two functors, full functors?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, torsion-groups

Ler $\mathcal{G}$, $\mathcal{G_0}$ and $\mathcal{G_{\infty}}$ be the category of abelian groyps, torsion abelian groups  and infinite abelian groups, respectively. The morphism of the first and second categories are group homomorphisms and the morphisms of the third category are injective group homomorphisms.

Are the following two functors, full functors?

$F_1: \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G_0}$ with $F_1(G)=Tor(G)$ the torsion subgroup.

$F_2:\mathcal{G_{\infty}} \to \mathcal{G}$ with 
$F_2(G)= Thin(G)$, the Thin subgroup of $G$. Thin subgroup of $G$ consist of all $g\in G$ such that the cyclic group $(g)$  has infinite index in $G$.

Comment: For $F_1$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467362/endomorphism-rings-and-torsion-subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the torsion subgroup functor, suppose it were full.  Then, for any abelian group $G$, there would be a map $G \to Tor(G)$ with image equal to the identity map $Tor(G) \to Tor(Tor(G)) = Tor(G)$.  This map would necessarily induce a splitting of $G$ as a direct sum of $Tor(G)$ and another subgroup.  However, not every abelian group $G$ has $Tor(G)$ as a direct summand - according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup (although I can't come up with any counterexample off the top of my head, and a quick Google search didn't turn up anything immediately either).

However, the restriction to the full subcategory of finitely generated abelian groups would be full.

Comment: A simple example where the torsion subgroup is not a summand is $G=\prod_p\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ where $p$ ranges over all primes.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer half of this.  $F_2$ is not full, since one can just take $G$ uncountable.  Then $Thin(G)=G$, and $G$ in general will have non-injective endomorphisms, but these will not be in the image of $F_2$ mapping the $\mathcal{G_{\infty}}$ endomorphisms of $G$ to the ordinary ones.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I revise the question.

Comment: What about if we consider the injective morphisms for $\mathcal{G}$ when we consider the second functor $F_2$?

Comment: I don't know.  You just made the problem much harder!